# Radio buttons created programmatically does not toggle

Tags: android, kotlin, radio-button

I am creating a radio group with two radio buttons programmatically. Initially one button is checked. On creation when I click the other button, the state of the originally checked button does not toggle.

```
        val medlayout: LinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.manuallayout)
        var inputgroup = RadioGroup(this)
        inputgroup.orientation = RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL
        medlayout.addView(inputgroup)

        var inputText = RadioButton(this)
        inputText.text = "Type Name"
        inputText.isChecked = true
        inputgroup.addView(inputText)

        var inputPic = RadioButton(this)
        inputPic.text = "Take a Photo"
        inputgroup.addView(inputPic)
```

What am I missing over here

[image]

Comment: I have found out the reason behind the problem. Since I am setting inputText.isChecked = true , It is never turned false. In that case my question would be how to set one button as true as a default case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the ID for radio buttons

```
val medlayout: LinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.manuallayout)
var inputgroup = RadioGroup(this)
inputgroup.orientation = RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL
medlayout.addView(inputgroup)

var inputText = RadioButton(this)
inputText.id = View.generateViewId()    // Set ID for inputText
inputText.text = "Type Name"
inputText.isChecked = true
inputgroup.addView(inputText)

var inputPic = RadioButton(this)
inputPic.id = View.generateViewId()    // Set ID for inputPic
inputPic.text = "Take a Photo"
inputgroup.addView(inputPic)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set id to your RadioButtons, Like this :

```
    val medlayout: LinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.ll)
    var inputgroup = RadioGroup(this)
    inputgroup.orientation = RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL
    medlayout.addView(inputgroup)

    var inputText = RadioButton(this)
    inputText.text = "Type Name"
    inputText.id = 0
    inputText.isChecked = true
    inputgroup.addView(inputText)

    var inputPic = RadioButton(this)
    inputPic.text = "Take a Photo"
    inputPic.id = 1
    inputgroup.addView(inputPic)
```